# Enum<T>.Parse allows parsing any string that is an integer. Is it a bug in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

If we try to call `Enum.Parse<T>` with a string integer (`"2"`, `"3"`, `"55"`, ...) parsing will succeed even if Enum does not define parsed value.

Here's sample code

```
public static class Program
{
    enum TestEnum
    {
        A = 0,
        B = 1,
        C = 2
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestEnum value = Enum.Parse<TestEnum>("4");
        Console.WriteLine(value); // outputs 4 to console

        bool result = Enum.TryParse<TestEnum>("4", out _);
        Console.WriteLine(result); // writes True 

        bool isDefined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TestEnum), "4");
        Console.WriteLine(isDefined); // writes False
    }
}
```

This behavior is unexpected in my opinion. We discovered a bug in our application because we used `Enum.TryParse` instead of `Enum.IsDefined`.

.net core version:

```
>dotnet --list-sdks
2.2.110 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.207 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

This output was from console running in debug mode using VS2017 (which means app was probably running under 2.2.110 runtime).

Is this a bug in .net core? I tried to find a bug report on .net core github repo, without luck.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netcore-2.2 its not a bug, its the correctr behaviour.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? 4 is a valid value for an enum.

Comment: @DavidG this behavior is too C-like in my opinion. Honestly I expected for TryParse to return fase, and Parse to throw an exception.

Comment: Then you need to understand what an enum is. It's just a glorified integer. The parse must succeed so we can have flag enumerations.

Comment: @DavidG I am aware of that, I just find it strange that for example parsing string that is not integer (and not valid enum value name) throw exception, and parsing string that is integer doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Enum_TryParse__1_System_String___0__):

> If `value` is the string representation of an integer that does not represent an underlying value of the `TEnum` enumeration, the method returns an enumeration member whose underlying value is `value` converted to an integral type. If this behavior is undesirable, call the `IsDefined` method to ensure that a particular string representation of an integer is actually a member of `TEnum`.

So it's not a bug, it's intended and documented behaviour.